# ¿como hago si quiero crear un bucle que repita 4 veces las mismas cosas, y que todas las veces que paso guarde datos en una lista?

Tags: python

```py
lista = [ ]
h = 0
while h < 4:
    nombre = input("Ingrese nombre:")
    edad = input("Ingrese edad:")
    lista = [nombre , edad]
    h += 1
```

### problema con listas

---

> quiero que en la lista se me guarden todos los nombres y todas las edades, osea 4 nombres y 4 edades

- nombre
- edad

Comment: Reemplaza la asignación  de lista por `lista.append([nombre,edad])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes resolver tu problema usando la función [append](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_append.asp), como comentó Christian, de forma que tu código queda de esta forma:

```
lista = [ ]
h = 0
while h < 4:
    nombre = input("Ingrese nombre:")
    edad = input("Ingrese edad:")
    lista.append([nombre, edad])
    h += 1
```

De esa forma al imprimir la lista tendrás el resultado esperado.